# how to interpreter regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I am new to regular expression. in order to study it i am referring to Mastering regular expression.

```
`My regular expression is`

    [a-z\s]{3,10}


and the input string is 

cat is the cat
```

I am checking this on https://regex101.com. in the output i am getting "cat is the " if i change the regular expression to [a-z\s]{1,10} than also i get the same result. so i am unable to get how this output is cumming.

Comment: `{3,10}` means between 3 and 10. `{1,10}` means between 1 and 10 so max allowed is 10 in both case hence matching same text in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noramlly regex engine would scan for a match in a string from left to right. Here, the actual regex is `[a-z\s]{3,10}` , it would match 10 chars of lowercase letters or spaces from the start since it was greedy. `{3,10}` repeats the previous token `[a-z\s]` min of three times and the max of 10 times. If the line contain lowercase letters or spaces of length `9`, this regex would match that line also because 9 falls within the range `3`, `10`

`[a-z\s]{1,10}` also do the same job of matching 10 chars of lowercase letters or spaces from the start. `{1,10}` would repeat the previous token `[a-z\s]` minimum 1 time and the maximum of 10 times. So this also matches a line which has  single character but the above regex matches a substring which must have at-least three characters.

Comment: thanks. one more thing i want to ask if my string is "ca9t is the cat " and mine regular expression is same as [a-z\s]{3,10} than the output string i get is "t is the cat ". My doubt is that why it did not gave the string "ca" instead of "t is the cat".

Comment: it won't return `ca` because it has two chars only but the regex expects atleast 3 and at most 10 to match.  So match can't be possible on `ca` but it would be possible on `t is the cat `

Comment: ok and what it will do to 9 in the string it will skip it. That means it pick a character from string than compares with the regular expression rule.

Comment: it skips `9` because the pattern we gave is `[a-z\s]`. So this won't match a digit. `[a-z\s]{3,10}` would finds a match on the strings which has at-least three continuous chars (alphabets or spaces).

Comment: still in the character class of the regular expression the [a-z\s] does not contains digits than if it like this than the regular expression should fail.when it encounters 9 in the string.

Comment: `[...]` block is called character class in regex. Yep, it would fail once it find any other character in-between. `foo` will would be matched but `f9o` won't be matched. BUt in this string `fff9fff`, it would find two substrings `fff` and `fff`

Comment: Yes this is what i understand what you just told, but sorry i am little bit confuse not able to get. As in our case the regular expression was [a-z\s]{3,10}. and the string was ca9t is the cat. than as you stated above when it encounters 9 after "ca" in the string the regular expression. Than to regular expression should fail. This is confusing me.

Comment: ok, at first the our regex `[a-z\s]{3,10}` won't touch any characters other than lowercase letters or spaces. In this example `ca9t is the cat`, regex engine would skipp the character 9. Now we have `ca`, `t is the cat` . Then the regex engine tries to apply the regex on both sets. First one fails since it has two chars and the second one passes since it has atleast 3.

Comment: i finally got this. if our regular expression is changed to [a-z\s]* than again our string is "ca9t is the cat" than this time the output is "ca" and not "ca t is the cat". So why this time it did not skip 9 and again matches the rest of the string

Comment: you really need to study the basics of regex. `[a-z\s]* ` , `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times, so `ca` has two charcaters. A match found.

Comment: oops i am literally dump. I got i was so into that that even i did not think of this " * ". Thanks dude for helping me.